# Javascript syntax: equal signs and commas

Tags: javascript, variables, syntax

I really didn't know what to call this question, neither what I could google for. I'm trying to understand the source code for the D3.js library and I've encountered two functions that I simply can't understand, due to the syntax that is new to me.

The first one is the number interpolator:

```
function d3_interpolateNumber(a, b) {
  b -= a = +a;
  return function(t) { return a + b * t; };
}
```

What's going on on the second line here? We're subtracting the value of `b` from the value of `a` and then...uhm, you lost me. How does this syntax work?

The other thing that confuses me, that I've seen in other places as well, is where the right-hand assignment of a variable consists of several variables separated by commas. As in:

```
var i = d3.interpolators.length, f;
```

What does this mean? These snippets are taken from https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/interpolate/number.js and
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/interpolate/interpolate.js

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The first line you're asking about is just two assignments. It's equivalent to this:

```
a = +a;
b -= a;
```

The `+a` is using the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#-_.28Unary_Negation.29) to convert a string to a number. So we are converting `a` to a number and then subtracting that number from `b` (and reassigning the new value to `b`).

The second bit of syntax you're asking about is simply a list of variable declarations. For example:

```
var a, b, c; // Declares 3 variables, all initialised to undefined
```

That's equivalent to this:

```
var a;
var b;
var c;
```

In your example, one of the declarations in the list also includes an assignment. Any number of them can, so this is valid too:

```
var a, b = 1, c = true, d;
```

Comment: Life's good when smart people are around to explain stuff :) Thanks, this makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

The second line is

```
 b -= (a = +a);
```

Which means:

- set `a` to `+a` (conversion to a number). Return this value outside of the parentheses.
- Whatever value was returned, subtract it from b.

or

```
a=+a //converts a to an int
b-=a // or b=b-a
```

Remember, assignments return their value. So, `alert(a=1)` will alert `1`.

---

On the other hand,

```
var i = d3.interpolators.length, f;
```

splits to:

```
var i = d3.interpolators.length;
var f;
```

This is just basically a way of saying "var applie to the following comma separated list"

Comment: you did not explain what is +a . @James did explain that.

Comment: "conversion to an integer"... Note that the unary plus operator will handle floating point numbers, not just integers.

Comment: @JamesAllardice: whoops. Fixed

Comment: @simplecoder: I did. "conversion to a number". Which is technically more correct than what James wrote, since it works on booleans as well.

Comment: Three good answers. Too bad you can't accept them all. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An assignment is also an expression, which returns the value that is assigned. So this:

```
b -= a = +a;
```

is the same as:

```
b -= (a = +a);
```

or:

```
a = +a;
b -= a;
```

---

If the right hand side would really be values separated by comma, i.e:

```
var i = (d3.interpolators.length, f);
```

then the comma operator returns the value of the last operand, so it would be the same as:

```
d3.interpolators.length;
var i = f;
```

However, without the parentheses the comma is a separator between declared variables, not the comma operator, so it's the same as:

```
var i = d3.interpolators.length;
var f;
```